# Double q learning

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning

Can we expect that the two q tables converge together? which means that `abs(Q1-Q2).max()` converge to zero, Can we say that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community My question is general. It is not about a specific problem. My question is that if the two q tables gradually converge together so that we should have almost the same q tables at the end?

Comment: Yes, the double Q learning paper proves this on page 5 https://papers.nips.cc/paper_files/paper/2010/hash/091d584fced301b442654dd8c23b3fc9-Abstract.html